# Spacing around table and figure environments

Tags: spacing, floats

I've got `table` and `figure` environments, some placed "here" with `h` and some arranged automatically. But all together I don't like the spacing above and below the `figure` and `table` environments.

I searched the internet and found tips to set `abovecaptionskip` and `belowcaptionskip`. Well since my tables and figures all have a caption below the actual `table`/`figure` `belowcaptionskip` allows me to set the `\vspace` between `table`/`figure` and the following text. But `abovecaptionskip` obviously just gives me `\vspace` between the `table`/`figure` and the caption, but not between the above text and the `table`/`figure`.

How to set the `\vspace` above and below `table`/`figure` correctly then?

Comment: Have a look at @Werner's excellent answer to [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36361/how-can-i-inject-the-proper-amount-of-vertical-space-between-captions-and-figure/36362#comment72508_36362](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36361/how-can-i-inject-the-proper-amount-of-vertical-space-between-captions-and-figure/36362#comment72508_36362)

Answer (score 20):

You are probably looking for the length `\intextsep` (at least). This is the space that is inserted to separate floats from the surrounding text.

Comment: How does one adjust this parameter?

Comment: @Roly this is how: `\setlength\intextsep{18pt}`

Answer (score 13):

One way would be to simply add the desired `\vspace` before and after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{MyFigure}[1][]{\begin{figure}[#1]\vspace{1.0cm}}{\vspace{1.0cm}\end{figure}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{MyFigure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=2cm]{foo}
    \caption{Figure: foo}
\end{MyFigure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also works for a negative space, as I have just found out.

Comment: underrated answer! +1

Answer (score 9):

Try adjusting the parameter `\intextsep`.

Comment: How does one adjust this parameter?

Comment: @Roly --- something like `\setlength\intextsep{10cm}` or `\addtolength\intextsep{1cm}`.

Answer (score 6):

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) can be used to add content at the start/end of an environment automatically. The following minimal example adds (up to) `5mm` to the top and bottom of the `figure` environment (via `\addvspace{5mm}`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\addvspace{5mm}}\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\addvspace{5mm}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering\includegraphics{image}
  \caption{This is a caption.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering\includegraphics{image}
  \caption{This is a caption.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The advantage with using `\addvspace` is that it only adds enough, making figures that end up on top of one another not add double the amount of space. See the [`\addvspace{<len>}` documentation](http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/latexdoc/ltx-198.html).

Comment: Hm, I get "undefined control sequenc" when I add the etoolbox package and use the AtBeginEnvironment..

Comment: @Meinzlein: You need to be a little more specific than that, since [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) recently added those patching commands. The most recent version of `etoolbox` on CTAN is `v 2.1 2011/01/03`. To see yours, add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and find the `etoolbox` entry *after* `**File List**` in your `.log` file.

Comment: Not working here either, inside a beamer class, probably interference with some other stuff I have...

Comment: @PatrickT: You can probably forego using `figure`s inside a [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation, as no-one would necessarily remember figures numbers associated with a `\caption`. Instead, *name* the figures or just use a `center` environment to place and caption them.

Comment: @Werner. Thanks. The ``figure``, ``table`` and ``center`` environments create too much space when they are immediately below the ``frametitle``. I often use the ``caption`` (without numbers), typeset in smaller font, so it's more convenient than a ``center`` environment. My workaround is adding ``\vspace{-1em}`` but I was looking for a more general fix. Your approach looked very promising. I don't really have time to make a MWE and post a question, so I'll stay with negative ``vspace`` for now. Thanks!

Comment: If the floats, well, _float_ to another place(s), the `\vskip`s stay at the point of figure's declaration. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493087/106612).

Comment: I got an error message telling me 
I was missing an item. This site gave the solution : http://joshua.smcvt.edu/latex2e/_005caddvspace.html So just add \par in front of \addvspace and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `\vspace{}` above `\begin{table}`

The example below adds 10mm of space above the table.

```
\vspace{10 mm} % add some space above the table

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular*}{0.7\textwidth}{ l r } % centered columns (2 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
Category & Score \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
a & b \\ % inserting body of the table
c & d \\
e & f \\
g &  h \\ [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular*}
% \caption{What a great table}
% \label{table:scores} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this can work if the float can respect the `h` option, it will leave an unwanted vertical space if the float must be moved.