# How to reduce space before image?

Tags: spacing, floats

I m using includegraphics function for image.

```
           Some text before image
          \begin{figure}
          \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{ABC.pdf}
          \caption{\textcolor{gray}{\footnotesize\textit{Some text}}}
          \end{figure}
```

I obeseve spacing is more between text (Some text before image) and image. How can i reduce it?

Comment: See the posts [`\vspace` around `table` and `figure` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38393/5764) and [How can I inject the proper amount of vertical space between captions and figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36361/5764) for some highlights on the lengths you might be after setting. In particular, `\intextsep` comes to mind.

Comment: I also used \vspace{-5mm} but when picture is on top, it overlaps with fancy header.