# Add \vspace{...} before and after every figure environment w/o

Tags: floats

I found this answer to another question [Spacing around table and figure environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38393/spacing-around-table-and-figure-environments).

I don't want to create a new environment for my figures. Instead I would like to edit the existing `figure` environment with the same `\vspace{...}` settings.

Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{MyFigure}[1][]{\begin{figure}[#1]\vspace{1.0cm}}{\vspace{1.0cm}\end{figure}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{MyFigure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=2cm]{foo}
    \caption{Figure: foo}
\end{MyFigure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not add `\vspace` at the beginning or ending of every `figure` because it would add this space also, if the `figure` moves e.g. to a float page or a top or bottom placed figure. If you want to change the vertical distance before and after *here* placed figures change `\intextsep`.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution with \intexsep. But in my case I need exactly what I asked for, because I need to make some more changes with the figure environment. So, is it possible to change the existing figure environment like the one I quoted in my question?

Comment: If you want other changes you should ask for other changes. And yes, you can patch existing macros and therefore environments using, e.g., [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch). Nevertheless, I would not recommend to use this to add vertical space before or after figures.