# etoolbox: AtBeginEnvironment is not At Begin Environment

Tags: etoolbox

I tried the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{AtBeginEnvironment\par}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{AtEndEnvironment\par}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{table}{BeforeBeginEnvironment\par}
\AfterEndEnvironment{table}{AfterEndEnvironment\par}

\begin{document}
    Text before\par
\begin{table} [t]%
    Table text\par
\end{table}
    Text after\par
\end{document}
```

and got the following result:

```
Table text
AtEndEnvironment
Text before
BeforeBeginEnvironment
AtBeginEnvironment
AfterEndEnvironment
Text after
```

I was expecting AtBeginEnvironment to travel to the top of the page together with the float.
Here is what the manual has to say on the matter:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{<environment>}{<code>}
Appends arbitrary <code> to a hook executed by the \begin command
at the beginning of a given <environment>, immediately before
\<environment>, inside the group opened by \begin.
```

I do not know what happens inside an environment definition; I guess it declares some special commands called `\<environment>` (e.g. `\table`) and `\end<environment>` (e.g. `\endtable`).

But in this case, shouldn't it be `immediately after \<environment>`, in order to be a complement to `\AtEndEnvironment` just as `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` is a complement to `\AfterEndEnvironment`?

Anyway, how can I add code to the beginning of an environment? I'm trying to set a certain font style for all tables, and `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\small}` does not work. Also I guess this behavior makes [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38407) answer incorrect, because `\addvspace` would stay at the point of declaration of the figure instead of moving together with it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `etoolbox` package redefines `\begin` so that

1. `\@beforebegin@<envname>@hook` is executed
2. a group is started
3. the usual bookkeeping is performed (setting `\@currenvir`, for instance)
4. `\@begin@<envname>@hook` is executed
5. the macro `\<envname>` is executed

Thus what you get is

```
\@beforebegin@table@hook
\begingroup
<bookkeeping>
\@begin@table@hook
\table
```

The macro `\table` is responsible for starting the creation of a float and expands to `\@float{table}`.

Thus the tokens `AtBeginEnvironment\par` and `BeforeBeginEnvironment\par` are seen and the paragraphs are typeset *before* the float is started.

To the contrary, `\end` is redefined to execute the `\AtEndEnvironment` tokens before `\end<envname>` is executed.

This should explain the output you get.

There is a hook for doing things when the float has already begun and is `\@floatboxreset`.

I would be wary of using the hooks for adding text: they're meant for additional setup.

Answer (score 2):

In case you intended to use this to, say, globally adjust the formatting of tables and figures, the following would be a work-around:

```
% Redefine figure environment so that all figures are centered and use tiny sans-serif font
\makeatletter
\let\figureorig\figure
\def\figure@i[#1]{\figureorig[#1]\centering\sffamily\tiny}  % with optional argument
\def\figure@ii{\figureorig\centering\sffamily\tiny}  % without optional argument
\def\figure{\@ifnextchar[\figure@i \figure@ii}  % Redefine depending on presence of [
\makeatother

% Redefine table environment so that all tables are set in tiny sans-serif font
\makeatletter
\let\tableorig\table
\def\table@i[#1]{\tableorig[#1]\sffamily\tiny}  % with optional argument
\def\table@ii{\tableorig\sffamily\tiny}  % without optional argument
\def\table{\@ifnextchar[\table@i \table@ii}  % Redefine depending on presence of [
\makeatother
```

The relatively complicated redefinition results from the fact that the `figure` and `table` environments can carry optional arguments. Thus, the redefinition looks for an opening square bracket “[” in order to determine whether an optional argument is provided or not.