# Spacing before and after section titles

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I know this subject has been mentioned before, but I'm still having a problem in creating a space under a section title. I used the `titlesec` package and then tried using the command `\titlespacing{\section}`...

This is my code. Can anybody help?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\huge}
\sectionfont{\Huge}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Kapitel 1}
\section*{Einleitung}
\begin{large}
\subsection*{1.1 Motivation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Thanks! But sorry I didn't get what you mean. So leave the titlespacing and just use the \\ to make the spaces?

Comment: @user29019 but exactly what kind of space are you trying to get? Exactly how much space do you want after \chapter and `\section`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes I tried it, it works. The \begin{large} is for the font size of the text. So everything is working till now. But I need create a titlespacing under the 'Einleitung' so between the section title und the text beneath it. I'm a new LaTeX user, I'm writing a scientific thesis. so there would be chapters, section and subsections. I searched in the internet for packages and commands I found things like \vspace, \titlespacing{\section}... but non of them worked, I compile the .tex file through a terminal (ubuntu) but I get no changes.

Comment: So I need like about 3 empty lines between section title and subsection title!

Comment: @abdu please compile the following test document *exactly* as it is: `\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{8.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Kapitel 1}
\section{Einleitung}
\subsection{Motivation}

\end{document}`. Is it something like that what you need?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes! That's what I need! So how can I change the spacings? What are these numbers? 3.5ex? Can I also do the same for the Chapter? And does this also work with the document class 'report'? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, by the way, do you think that the packages conflict with each other? your code worked. I then added the spacing command to my code, and it didn't work. And one more question, I always get the error 'no line here to end', shall I just ignore it? Or can I avoid it somehow? Thanks! 

Ok I think sectsty and titlesec don't like each other. I just tried both together in a simple code, and the titlespacing didn't work again, so this is the problem I think.

Comment: @abdu please see my answer. The error "there's no line here to end" appears because perhaps you are using `\\` incorrectly.

Comment: Similar question, [sectioning - Reducing spacing after headings - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53338/reducing-spacing-after-headings)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package you can use `\titlespacing*` you can change the spacing before and after the title; the syntax of the command is:

```
\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
```

(there's an additional optional argument, but it's not important here). `<left>` increases the left margin; `<before-sep>` controls the vertical space before the title; `<after-sep>` controls the vertical space after the title. (Please refer to the package documentation for further information). A complete example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Kapitel 1}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Einleitung}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Motivation}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `ex` (approximately the height of an "x" in the current font) as the unit for the lengths used, but you can use instead any other valid LaTeX unit (`cm`, `in`, `mm`, `pt`, among others); you can also use multiples of predefined lengths such as \baselineskip:

```
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
  {0pt}{2\baselineskip}{3\baselineskip}
```

I used ex since in this way the space is font-dependent. If you want to change the formatting of the titles, you can also use the same package and its powerful `\titleformat` command.

Comment: thanks very much! Everything worked, so now I know that I only have to use the titlesec package. I used the cm unit to change the spacing before the chapter and it worked! However I still have a problem, the one with the error. I can ignore it but it bothers while compiling through the terminal. I usually seperate two paragraphs with \\ \\ and this makes the error I think. Is there a way I can seperate paragraphs?

Comment: @abdu Yes, using two consecutive \\ commands will result in errors. You can use `\par\bigskip` instead at the end of each paragraph. Another option would be to load the [`parskip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package which automatically suppresses indentation and increases separation between paragraphs. Yet another option would be to switch to  the document class `scrreprt` and use its `parskip` features.

Comment: \pas\bigskip worked. I tried the parskip package by defining the skip length: 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
and then typing \parskip between the paragraphs, but I got errors while compiling.

Comment: @abdu The idea with the `parskip` package is just to load it; no need to set `\parskip` nor to explicitly call `\parskip`. You don't need the line `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` (you can delete it) and you don't need to use `\parskip` in your document.

Comment: alright! I'll just use \par\bigskip. Thanks one more time for all the infos, a big help!

Comment: Why do you use parameters such as `5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex`? Why not just `6.3ex`?

Comment: @Adam_G The first option allows for stretching or shrinking; the second one, doesn't.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - I'm not sure I understand this.

Comment: @Adam_G `texdoc texbytopic` (or *The TeXbook*) and search for glue. The answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64756/3954 can also give you an explanation.

Comment: How do you keep one of the non-optional arguments the same (default)? I only want to change the `<after sep>`.

Comment: To answer my own question: you can look up the default values in section 9.2 of the package documentation (linked in above answer)

Comment: instead of `5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex` can I just use `-0.5mm` ?

Answer (score 31):

If you don't need all the "baggage" of an additional package like `titlesec`, you can simply modify these aspects of your headings yourself.  See this example.  I use a few sections and save the original section definition, so we can see a comparison.

I then define and use a section "prelude" prior to the invocation of the original section command.  Then I add a "postlude" to the sectioning command.  The prelude and the postlude here both add an extra `em` of vertical space, but you could use it to put in other sectioning highlights like rules, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}

This is the first line of text.  Note the vertical spacing.  

\section{Second Section}

Observe the spacing prior to and following the sectioning command. Now let me
redefine a few things.

\makeatletter
\let\origsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar{\starsection}{\nostarsection}}

\newcommand\nostarsection[1]
{\sectionprelude\origsection{#1}\sectionpostlude}

\newcommand\starsection[1]
{\sectionprelude\origsection*{#1}\sectionpostlude}

\newcommand\sectionprelude{%
  \vspace{1em}
}

\newcommand\sectionpostlude{%
  \vspace{1em}
}
\makeatother

\section{Next Section}
Did this text drop 1em lower relative to the heading than the prior
section?  If so, we have succeeded.

\section{Final Section}

And the result is permananent, as you can see.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer Steven. But I think I'll use the titlesec package just because I know how it works now. And since I'm using the report class I need chapters sections and subsections it's makes more sense to use the titlesec package. But thanks a lot, I'll save your code and try to use it in the future! =)

Comment: @abdu.  I understand completely.  It's just one more option, depending on the particular need.

Comment: Nice! How would this work if I wanted to do the same for `\subsection*`'s?

Comment: @texfan If you take my source and do a global search and replace from `section` to `subsection`, recompile and see the result.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ah ok, I thought maybe there was a way to do both at once, but this works, thanks :)!

Comment: @texfan The only duplicative code would occur if you wanted the `\sectionprelude` to be identical to the `\subsectionprelude` (also for postlude).  Then, you could have a common prelude/postlude, without duplication.

Answer (score 12):

In case anybody wants to adjust the spaces while using KOMAscript -- @gonzalo's answer is not recommended since KOMA and titlesec are incompatible. However, KOMA provides commands to modify the section commands. The command

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-5.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,afterskip=4.3ex plus -.2ex]{section}
```

modifies the space before and after a section title to similar values.

Comment: This is a very important "detail" indeed! Note that the negative vale for beforeskip doesn't work too well, but the command itself is exactly what is needed when using e.g. \documentclass{scrartcl}

Answer (score 7):

To control **each space individually** you can simply use:

`\vspace{5mm}` or `\vspace{1em}` or `\vspace{1cm}` to **increase** (to **add space**) and;

`\vspace{-5mm}` or `\vspace{-1em}` or `\vspace{-1cm}` to **decrease** (**take from the standard space**).

> It is most suitable to control few sections of the standard space.

Follow a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm, top=20mm,}

\title{Spacing before and after section titles, \LaTeX}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{\huge Increase \Large space between headings and text}

\subsection{With (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{4mm\}})}
\vspace{4mm}
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. 

\subsection{With (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{0.5em\}})}
\vspace{0.5em}
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. 

\subsection{With (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{0.6cm\}})}
\vspace{0.6cm}
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. 

\vspace{1cm}
\hrulefill
\vspace{1cm}

\section{\huge Decrease \Large space between headings and text}

\subsection{With (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{-3.5mm\}})}
\vspace{-3.5mm}
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. 

\subsection{With (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{-1em\}})}
\vspace{-1em} 
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. 

\subsection{With (\texttt{\textbackslash vspace\{-0.44cm\}})}
\vspace{-0.44cm}
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it was tested here and works fine.