# Lyx - Set vertical margins or space between two sections

Tags: lyx

I would like to change the spacing between the sections of a document. Changing the margins values seem to have no effect. What can I do ?
Thanks,

Comment: Do mean the section headings, or individual paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, all the section headings

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles helps.

Comment: It is the space between the end of a section and the beginning of a new one, not the space between a section title and the text.

Comment: Yes, and to quote Gonzalo's answer: '*`<before-sep>` controls the vertical space before the title*'

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Lyx, where can I change <before-sep> ?

Comment: You add the command Gonzalo used in his answer in Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble. So you need `\usepackage{titlesec}` and the `\titlespacing` command, with the spacing you like. Add all to the preamble.

Comment: Ok, the solution by Gonzalo works !