# Remove spaces between various elements

Tags: spacing

I am trying to remove the space between the elements that I show in the following image. The space I talk about is denoted by the gray line (that line is not produced by LaTeX, it is merely a way to visualize the space in question)

[image]

To be more exact the spaces I want to reduce are:

1. Space between sections and subsections
2. Space between sections/subsections and text/images/math
3. Space between text images and math

How can I do that?

I have tried to use the followings but they didn't give me a good result and a good way to handle the spaces with precision.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[   
    top = 0.2in,
    bottom = 0.2in,
    left = 0.2in,
    right = 0.2in,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[fontsize=8pt]{scrextend}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}

\columnseprule=0.8pt

\begin{multicols*}{4}

\section*{Section Title 1}

\subsection*{Subsection Title 1}

Text here

\subsection*{Subsection Title 2}
%
\begin{align*}
&x+y=1\\
&x+z=2
\end{align*}


\subsection*{Subsection Title 3}

\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{1.png}
%
\begin{equation*}
x+y=1
\end{equation*}

\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{2.png}

\subsection*{Subsection Title 4}

\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{1.png}
%
\begin{equation*}
x+y=1
\end{equation*}

\end{multicols*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Related?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles  At least insofar as section titles.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I mention in my question that this is one the ways I tried and didn't quite work. Thanks though. :)

Comment: The cited question has more than one answer.

Comment: If you want 'precision' why are you using rubber lengths?

Comment: @jon I don't even know what rubber length means! :P

Comment: Look at TeX primitives `\baselineskip`, `\lineskiplimit`, `\lineskip`. Nothing more is needed. LaTeX (unfortunately) makes things more complicated.

Comment: `12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt` is 'rubber': you are asking for 12pt plus 4pts worth of possible stretch and up to 2pts worth of 'shrink'. `12pt` by itself would not stretch or shrink.

Comment: somewhere after `\begin{document}` insert the line \showthe\parskip` and see what it says (it will report on your screen, and halt the job temporarily).  then add `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` and try again; see if there's any difference.  that's only part of the story, but it does play a part.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It doesn't pause and doesn't say anything (I want to mention that I use ShareLaTeX).

Comment: @jon Useful point!

Comment: @Adam -- okay, i'm not a sharelatex user.  if you have a log file (you should, but on-line services often hide them) it will show the result.  but you should also see some difference in the outputs from the runs with/without resetting `\parskip`.

Comment: Also, you should note that `\titlespacing` doesn't define the vertical spacing before and after a section title, but what is *added* to the normal `\baselineskip`.