# How to remove spaces between paragraph and lines?

Tags: spacing

[image]

In given below text, I want to remove space between "diverse areas" to "2.1.1 Brief...".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The answer to your question will depend a lot on the class, style, and packages used. Moreover, do you want to remove just *that* space or *all* the vertical spaces before sub-subsections?

Comment: There are several answers at this question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles, that may provide you a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my answer at [Spacing before and after section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles/108824#108824), but with space removed rather than added.  Here, I use `\sectionprelude` and if needed, `\sectionpostlude` to modify the default space before and after section headings.  However, they can also be used to add ruled lines and other such stylistic modifications to the section head appearance.

Obviously, similar things can be done for subsections, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\let\origsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar{\starsection}{\nostarsection}}

\newcommand\nostarsection[1]
{\sectionprelude\origsection{#1}\sectionpostlude}

\newcommand\starsection[1]
{\sectionprelude\origsection*{#1}\sectionpostlude}

\newcommand\sectionprelude{%
  \vspace{-4ex}% STUFF TO DO PRIOR TO THE SECTION HEADING
}

\newcommand\sectionpostlude{%
%  \vspace{-2.5ex}% STUFF TO DO FOLLOWING THE SECTION HEADING
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]