# parskip subsection header spacing

Tags: spacing, titlesec, parskip

I am using the `parskip` package for two reasons:

1. To add a space between paragraphs.
2. To remove the indentation of a first line in a paragraph.

However, this package makes the spacing before and after a subsection heading be absurdly wide. I have tried using the `\titlespacing` macro from the `titlesec` package to modify that whitespace, but it seems like the other package rules out this one. It just isn't taking any effect.

How can I reduce that space?

Comment: Take my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles/108824#108824 and do three things: 1) add `\usepackage{parskip}`; 2) change all occurrences of `section` to `subsection`; and 3) change the prelude and postlude definitions to something with negative `\vspace` as for example, `\newcommand\subsectionprelude{\vspace{-1em}}`

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of what you have, particularly about ”the other package [which] rules out" `titlesec`

Comment: @egreg The issue is solved, and I did say what "the other package" is (`titlesec`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the advice of my comment (utilizing my answer at [Spacing before and after section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles/108824#108824)), but applying the result to subsections, and reducing the spacing.

EDITED to take Gustavo's suggestions: 1) implementing optional argument to `\subsection`; and 2) using `-\parskip` as the adjusted vertical height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{Without Fix}

Blah blah 

\subsection{First subsection}

This is the first line of text.  Note the vertical spacing.  

\subsection{Second subsection}

Observe the spacing prior to and following the subsectioning command. Now let me
redefine a few things.

\makeatletter
\let\origsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection{\@ifstar{\starsubsection}{\nostarsubsection}}

\newcommand\nostarsubsection[2][\relax]{%
  \subsectionprelude%
  \ifx\relax#1\origsubsection{#2}\else\origsubsection[#1]{#2}\fi%
  \subsectionpostlude}

\newcommand\starsubsection[2][\relax]{%
  \subsectionprelude%
  \ifx\relax#1\origsubsection*{#2}\else\origsubsection*[#1]{#2}\fi%
  \subsectionpostlude}

\newcommand\subsectionprelude{%
  \vspace{-\parskip}% OR ANY OTHER DESIRED VALUE
}

\newcommand\subsectionpostlude{%
  \vspace{-\parskip}% OR ANY OTHER DESIRED VALUE
}
\makeatother

\section{With Fix}

Blah blah

\subsection[Alternate TOC title]{Next subsection}
Did this text raise parskip higher relative to the heading than the prior
subsection?  If so, we have succeeded.

\subsection*{Non-numbered subsection}

Here is some text.

\subsection{Final subsection}

And the result is permananent, as you can see.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest adding support for the optional argument?  It’s pretty easy using, _e.g._, `xparse`.

Comment: Also, shouldn’t it be `\vspace{-\parskip}`?  Sorry for withholding my upvote, but I think that the answer can be improved… (:-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Done.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that I cannot understand, Steven declined my suggestion of using `xparse`.  However, I deem that an answer along these lines could be of some interest, so I am supplying it myself.

I’ll espouse Steven’s approach of making no assumption whatsoever on how `\subsection` is implemented:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let \originalSubsection \subsection
\RenewDocumentCommand \subsection { s o m } {%
    \vspace{-\parskip}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \originalSubsection*{#3}%
    }{%
        \IfValueTF{#2}{%
            \originalSubsection[#2]{#3}%
        }{%
            \originalSubsection{#3}%
        }%
    }%
    \vspace{-\parskip}%
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{With Fix}

Blah blah.

\subsection*{A starred subsection}
This subsection has no number, and is not included in the ToC\@.

\subsection{Normal subsection}
This subsection is normal in all respects: it is numbered, and appears in the 
ToC\@ with the same title as above.

\subsection[Short title]{A somewhat longer title}
Numbered subsection, but with a different title in the ToC\@.

\subsection*[Ignored argument]{This is possible too\ldots}
\ldots and it is a well-known issue; it doesn't hurt, anyway!

\end{document}
```