# How do I adjust vertical spacing above \rule line to match that below the line?

Tags: rules, parskip, vspace, shortstack

I want to know how to adjust vertical spacing above `\rule` line to match that below the line. I have attempted to solve this problem using the solutions presented for similar questions [hrulefill vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454389/hrulefill-vertical-spacing) and [parskip subsection header spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324344/parskip-subsection-header-spacing), but they do not seem to work for my issue. Below I have provided a piece of output and reproducible code similar to what's used in my document.

**Here is some output similar to mine:**

[image]

**Here is the code I used to generate the output above:**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document} %starts document
\raggedright%prevents hyphenation, kick words that make line over full to next line
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\textit{Technical Guidance Bulletin No. 18 – April 2019}

\vspace{.5ex}
\noindent

\relsize{2}{\textbf{Efficacy of Commercial-Scale Propagation of Native Baitfish in Arizona}}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do this manually with `\rule[1.7ex]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}`

Comment: Your suggestion works...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Shortstack` it!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{relsize,stackengine}
\begin{document} %starts document
\noindent
\setstackgap{S}{1.5ex}%
\setstackEOL{\\}%
\Shortstack[l]{
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\
\textit{Technical Guidance Bulletin No. 18 – April 2019}\\
\parbox{\textwidth}{\relsize{2}\bfseries\raggedright 
  Efficacy of Commercial-Scale Propagation of Native Baitfish in Arizona}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works...Thanks.