# How to landscape one chapter and make the gap between the title and the side of the page smaller than default?

Tags: spacing, chapters, landscape

I would like to have one of my chapters to be landscape instead of portrait. However, there is one problem: the gap between the chapter title after being landscaped is very big. I tried to reduce it by both `\vspace{-5cm}` and `\hspace{-5cm}`, but there is no use.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

My current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}

\newpage

\begin{landscape}

\chapter{ABC}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
%Table
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/ (Spacing before and after section titles). Depending on your document class there may be different approaches (e. g. memoir, KOMA, standard).

Comment: your example can not be run at all  as it had no `\documentclass` (so it is impossible to guess the definition of `\chapter` or see the gap that you are asking about)

Comment: Just updated the code.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have come across similar answers. However, in this case, I would like only one chapter to have less gap to the top of the page. The other chapters should be left intact. How should I do it?