# How can I prevent double spacing when paragraph ends in display maths?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, sectioning, paragraphs

I prefer to write documents with paragraph spacing rather than indents to distinguish different paragraphs, but my problem is that if a paragraph ends in display maths then this leaves a double spacing (since I also have display maths set with 1em above and below)is there a way of avoiding this annoying double spacing?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\jot}{0.5em}

\section{Section 1}
When I have text like this bit here, shortly followed by an equation such as
$$E = mc^2$$

\section{Section 2}
And a new section is started afterward, there is a double spacing between the end of the Maths and the start of section 2.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add a section 3, you will see that the space allocated after the math closing out section 1 is no different than the space allocated after the text closing out section 2.  Also, in LaTeX, use `\[...\]` delimiters for  unnumbered math, rather than `$$...$$`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It can be tricky to reset a low-level parameter such as `\parskip` directly. Don't do it. Instead, load the [parskip](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package first, and then (if you must) modify the `\parskip` length parameter. Whatever you do, don't make `\parskip` a rigid length; do give it some stretchability (in the TeX-related sense of the word).

Comment: @Mico I have never considered `\parskip` a low-level parameter.  Just sayin'.  However, the OP needs to understand that that `\parskip` gets wrapped up in the spacing before section headers.

Comment: Perhaps this question can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - See the documentation of the `parskip` package for why it can be tricky to set `\parskip` naively (to a nonzero length, that is).

Comment: @Mico I suppose you are talking about list skips and such?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Indeed, a non-zero value of `\parskip` can wreak havoc on the appearance of lists.

Comment: Yet another reason to use indents to indicate the start of a paragraph, not a blank line. Indentation has been the preferred way since the late 15th century.

Comment: Thanks for the help, all - makes more sense now. Is there a particular reason that $$ shoudn't be used as a delimiter?