# How to use optional arguments of the original commands in a macro?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'd like to use sectioning commands inside macros in order to enhance them, i.e. put some kind of line before and thing after the heading.

Is it possible to use/address the optional arguments of the original commands in the macro, e.g. `\subsection`?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
blindtext
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
multicol,
xcolor,
}

\newcommand{\specialheadline}[1]{%
{\centering
\color{gray}\rule{0.9\columnwidth}{1pt}\color{black}\par}
\subsection{#1}}

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Title stuff
\end{center}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}
\specialheadline{ASDF}
%\specialheadline[123]{ASDF} -- THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK

\blindtext[1]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My answer here might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles/108824#108824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following definition is probably better since it doesn't require switching back to `black`, because you could have a different colour preceding `\specialheadline`:

```
\newcommand{\specialheadline}[2][]{%
  {\centering
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule{0.9\columnwidth}{1pt}}\par}
  % How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/5764
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \subsection{#2}%
  \else
    \subsection[#1]{#2}%
  \fi}
```

It checks whether the optional argument supplied to `\specialheadline` is empty or not and conditions to setting the appropriate sectional unit. You could shorten the explicit conditioning to something like this:

```
\subsection[\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax #2\else #1\fi]{#2}
```

since the `\if`...`\fi` will be expanded as needed for the ToC.

A more reliable option would be to use [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse)'s command definition with `\IfValueTF` conditional though:

```
% \usepackage{xparse}% If you have LaTeX2e < 2020-10
\NewDocumentCommand{\specialheadline}{ o m }{%
  {\centering
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule{0.9\columnwidth}{1pt}}\par}
  % How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/5764
  \subsection[\IfValueTF{#1}{#1}{#2}]{#2}}
```