# Shaded environment with different heights at the beginning of shaded area

Tags: environments, framed, shading

I created an environment to shade some text I deem important. However, what I have within this environment can vary from a simple paragraph to an actual section or subsection. The problem is that the spacing before the text increases with the importance of the heading. I believe this is normal behavior, but in the book I'm writing it is too exaggerated for even `subsubsection`. Is there a way to reduce this space in a simple manner? I guess one could try to determine in the macro whether a new section, subsection, or just a paragraph is passed, and subtract vertical space with negative `\vspace` but I guess this would not be a simple solution. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.85}%

\newenvironment{advanced}{\par \begin{shaded*} \small}{\par\end{shaded*}}

\begin{document}


\begin{advanced}
\section{Section}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{advanced}

\begin{advanced}
\subsection{Subsection}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{advanced}

\begin{advanced}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{advanced}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

Comment: Can https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/spacing-before-and-after-section-titles help you? For example, add `\usepackage{titlesec}`and `\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}` in the preamble (but the spacing is also modified for non framed sections ; it's probably also better to provide rubber lengths as `1ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex` instead of fixed lengths as `1ex`, in particular for vertical space after the title). Change `\subsection` in the same way.

Comment: If it will modify non-framed sections then it's not a solution to the problem. I need this to happen only locally to the `advanced` environment I created.