# Which macros define spaces around table and float environments?

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, captions

I am trying to define the length of vertical space between tables and text globally in my document. So far, I have been using

```
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0cm}
    \setlength{\floatsep}{0cm}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0cm}
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0mm}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0cm}
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0mm}
```

in my preamble. Moreover, I also use the caption package, which I define as follows:

```
\usepackage[%
    font=small,
    textfont=bf,
    nooneline,
    justification=raggedright,
    format=hang,
    labelsep=quad,
    skip=0mm
]{caption}
```

I don't want the space to be zero, of course, but even if it is set to zero, I still have white space between tables and text as well as caption and text. This leads me to believe that there are more macros involved through whom the space between tables/captions and text is defined. I couldn't find a complete list of the macros involved, however (I looked e.g. [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#LaTeX_default_lengths) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36361/how-can-i-inject-the-proper-amount-of-vertical-space-between-captions-and-figure/36362#comment72508_36362)).

Are there still macros missing from the list above that potentially change the spacing between tables/captions and text?

EDIT:

A typical table in my document:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{...}
\label{...}
\end{table}
```

Where option `H` requires the `float` package.

Comment: There is no additional space added but it is possible that the text on the page can only break in certain places so there may be a "gap" between the text body and the floats. If you define the spaces to be 0pt with no stretch component any such gap is probably not filled and so you will get underfull vbox in the output routine warnings.

Comment: You should always include a complete document that shows the problem. Perhaps you are adding extra white space (eg with `\begin{center}` but if you don't show, we can't say.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am using a center environment around the table, but I did not know that adds additional space. If I want greater control over spacing, should I switch to using `\centering` instead?

Comment: For single column floats, there are similar ones for 2-column floats

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if this question will be closed. If not, feel free to submit you answer and I'll accept it.